# Any way to send file to A to B&C server using scp with file/password prompt

Tags: scp

Scenario:
Servers: A, B and C (All linux)

File:File.txt

Now i need to send the file from Server A to B&C using SCP but i have to enter the password and File name only once.

Need to know how to achieve it.

Tried `sshpass` but seems its not installed and i cannot install it :(

```
sshpass:command not found
```

Used code:(Here need to enter password each time)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter Package Name:\c"

read package

package1="$package"

echo

scp ${package1} User@ServerB:/tmp/

scp ${package1} User@ServerC:/tmp/
```

Comment: You could keep a directory on B&C constantly in sync using cron, then send the file to either B or C.

Comment: Can you please suggest how to keep in sync using cron?

Comment: Do you have to use `scp`? Do you have to type a password? There are many ways to do this, one of the better ways is without a password and using `sftp`.

Comment: In answer to your question about how to keep in sync using cron: you could set up an nfs share on C and have it accessible on B. Then just use cron to periodically rsync the two directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the "password" request like so. On the PC with the file (Server A), in a terminal type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048
Enter file in which to save the key (/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa): [Hit Enter]
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): [Hit Enter]
Enter same passphrase again: [Hit Enter]
Your identification has been saved in /<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

Then you need to copy `/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to Server B and C. On Server B and C, do the following. NOTE: The `mkdir -p ~/.ssh` may not be needed.

```
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
rm id_rsa.pub
```

Now you can connect from Server A to B and C without a password. For example, your script would now be as simple as (with a basic file check):

```
#!/bin/sh

ask () {
    echo -n "Enter Package Name: "
    read package

    if [ ! -f "$package" ]
    then
        echo "
${package} is not a file. Try again.
"
        ask
    else 
        upload "$package"
    fi
}

upload () {
    echo "put \"$1\" \"/tmp/$1\" > sftp.cmd
    sftp User@serverB < sftp.cmd
    sftp User@serverC < sftp.cmd
    rm -f sftp.cmd  
}

ask
exit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggestion.....My bad we don't have access to generate keygen :(...... Is there any other way to pass password as prompt only once so that no need to enter again and again for each Server...

Comment: Very surprised that [`ssh-keygen`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ssh-keygen) is not on Server A. This does not seem correct to me at all. Do you have a web server running PHP on the Server B & C? If so, you can always post the data to the server (over SSL / HTTPS) - again, no password needed. Would require `curl`, a web server on Server A or some other software to post the data to B & C.

Comment: Actually..we dont have access to check that...let me go with scp script by entering password each time...thnx a lot for all your time and responses....